# How to make auto select item in checkbox list with condition in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a checkbox list which the item is yes and no. For example, If textbox1 <= 90 then 1stitem in checkboxlist which is "Yes" will auto select. If textbox1 >90 then 2nditem in checkboxlist which is "No" will auto select. How to write this code in vb?

Thanks!

Comment: **Re-post** of [Auto check the checkboxlist in vb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28062954/auto-check-the-checkboxlist-in-vb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle OnTextChanged event of TextBox control. Following is a sample aspx file code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="Yes" Text="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="No" Text="No"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Back end code

```
Protected Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim valueString As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim value As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(valueString, value) Then
        If value <= 90 Then
            CheckBoxList1.Items.FindByValue("Yes").Selected = True
            CheckBoxList1.Items.FindByValue("No").Selected = False
        Else
            CheckBoxList1.Items.FindByValue("Yes").Selected = False
            CheckBoxList1.Items.FindByValue("No").Selected = True
        End If
     End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is in the textbox leave event, check the numeric value of the text and then check the appropriate value in the checkboxlist. You can use IsNumeric to make sure the value in the textbox is a number.